# Implementing Throughput Control in a Spring boot app using reactive Azure Cosmos client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure, project-reactor

I'm using Microsoft cosmos Nosql DB and a spring boot backend with the reactive cosmos client.

Theres a container Person.java, and the backend application does CRUD operations on it.

Below if existing code for it:

```
------------------------------------------------
Person.java
------------------------------------------------
package com.cosmos.containers;

import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.mapping.Container;
import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.mapping.PartitionKey;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Version;

@Container(containerName = "Person")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Person extends DomainEntity {

    @Id private String id;

    @PartitionKey private String partitionKey;

    private String name;
}
```

```
------------------------------------------------
CosmosDBConfig.java
------------------------------------------------
package com.cosmos.config;

import com.azure.core.credential.AzureKeyCredential;
import com.azure.cosmos.ConsistencyLevel;
import com.azure.cosmos.CosmosClientBuilder;
import com.azure.cosmos.DirectConnectionConfig;
import com.azure.cosmos.GatewayConnectionConfig;
import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.config.AbstractCosmosConfiguration;
import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.config.CosmosConfig;
import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.repository.config.EnableReactiveCosmosRepositories;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableReactiveCosmosRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.cosmos.repositories"})
@Slf4j
public class CosmosDBConfig extends AbstractCosmosConfiguration {

    private AzureKeyCredential azureKeyCredential;


    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "MyDataBase";
    }

    @Bean
    public CosmosClientBuilder cosmosDBClientBuilder() {
        this.azureKeyCredential = new AzureKeyCredential(<private key>);
        DirectConnectionConfig directConnectionConfig = new DirectConnectionConfig();
        GatewayConnectionConfig gatewayConnectionConfig = new GatewayConnectionConfig();
        return new CosmosClientBuilder()
                .endpoint(<url>)
                .credential(azureKeyCredential)
                .consistencyLevel(
                        ConsistencyLevel.valueOf("SESSION"))
                .multipleWriteRegionsEnabled(false)
                .preferredRegions(<my regions>)
                .directMode(directConnectionConfig, gatewayConnectionConfig);
    }


    @Override
    public CosmosConfig cosmosConfig() {
        return CosmosConfig.builder()
                .enableQueryMetrics(true)
                .maxDegreeOfParallelism(-1)
                .build();
    }


}
```

```
------------------------------------------------
PersonRepository.java
------------------------------------------------

package com.cosmos.repositories;

import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.repository.ReactiveCosmosRepository;

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends ReactiveCosmosRepository<Person, String> {

}
```

```
------------------------------------------------
MyPersonService.java
------------------------------------------------
@Service
public class MyPersonService {
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository repository;

    public Person save(Person person) {
        return repository.save(person);
    }
}
```

Now lets say I want to limit the usage of RUs for Person container to 1500 RUs/seconds using the ThroughputControlGroupConfig feature of java sdk in this code base([details docs of ThroughputControlGroupConfig can be found here](https://the9090rule.medium.com/controlling-an-applications-throughput-consumption-in-cosmos-db-with-throughputcontrolgroup-247cc0eafa92)).

How do I do this.

More specifically I want to know how to I pass his ThroughputControlGroupConfig to the `PersonRepository` class